# XPAGE Modal Dialog

Tags: xpages

How to hide the X (close) button in a standard modal dialog ?

[image]

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15973841/how-do-i-remove-the-close-icon-from-the-extlib-dialog

Comment: Bingo. It's a CSS way, but it should work :-)